# Blender Sculpt Brush changing when moving across mesh

Tags: modeling, sculpting, topology, brushes

When sculpting on a poly modeled mesh, with the multi-res modifier applied, the brush sometimes moves in a very stretched manner. All transformations are applied on the mesh also. It seems to happen mainly near the creases of the model.

[image: Normal sculpt brush]

[image: Stretched and distorted brush]

Comment: btw i see that crease. looks like you're using a mirror modifier? stick with symmetry X instead of mirror modifier when sculpting.

Comment: The mirror modifier has already been and this usually happens when near the arms also.